# Display element only while user is scrolling, without fading quirk

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show a table of contents (for a long web document) as a fixed element on the right side of the page.

I got a 'hello world' of this going fairly easily, but I can't figure out how to keep the element from fading in and out during long scrolls.

Scroll around enough on the fiddle and you'll see what I mean.

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XGY8H/2/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var toc = $('.tableOfContents');
    toc.fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function(){
        toc.fadeOut();
    },10000);       
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no JS in your fiddle.

Comment: @Florent thanks for pointing that out. just fixed it.

Comment: Scroll gets called frequently, so you should not trigger a timed animation event on every call. Set a flag/class on the element indicating if it has been triggered again and get a regular timer event to check the flag/class and fade out/reset the flag/class.

Comment: @oGeez I don't want the TOC to cover up content when they're not scrolling, so they can read everything on the page easily. But when they scroll, I assume they're looking for new content, so I want the TOC to appear again. Once they stop scrolling again, I assume they're reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cas use `clearTimeout` to prevent the ToC from fading out.

```
$(function () {
    var toc = $('.tableOfContents');
    var fadeTimer;

    toc.fadeOut();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        toc.fadeIn();

        if (fadeTimer) {
            clearTimeout(fadeTimer);
        }

        fadeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            fadeTimer = 0;
            toc.fadeOut();
        }, 10000);
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rCYQd/)

Comment: beautiful. I've never worked with timeouts before, but this makes how to do it very clear. Thanks!